# Circular dependency hell. Use value from previous row in current one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to calculate Bill of Materials and got stuck in some attributes calculation.

[This is link to Google sheets with all the data and needed formulas](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yxCEx-745YK9N59T7PwzP8iTxRgCEpwkj9Nh9_1BoZE/edit?usp=sharing)

I have
Quantity on Hand (@QOH) - 95
Safety Stock (@SS) - 58

```
DECLARE @qoh INT = 95
      , @ss  INT = 58
      , @eoq INT = 96;

CREATE TABLE #data
(
     PartId INT
  ,  SalesOrderQty INT
  , SalesDate     DATE
);

INSERT INTO #data (PartId
                 , SalesOrderQty
                 , SalesDate)
VALUES (1, 75, '20190101')
     , (1, 100, '20190201')
     , (1, 115, '20190301')
     , (1, 95, '20190401')
     , (1, 132, '20190501');
```

I need to calculate 3 entities:

- `@Supply` - if it is first record (20190101), then `@QOH-@SS-#data.SalesOrderQty`,
  otherwise `(Previous month)@RecommendedQty - #data.SalesOrderQty`
- `@EOQMultiplier` - `CEILING(ABS(@Supply/@eoq))`
- `@RecommendedQty` - if `@Supply <= 0` then `@EOQMultiplier * @eoq` ELSE `@Supply`

Expected data

```
|--------|----------|-------|---------------|-----------------|
| PartId | Date     |Supply | EOQMultiplier | RecommendedQty  |
|--------|----------|-------|---------------|-----------------|
| 1      | 20190101 | -38   | 1             | 96              |
| 1      | 20190201 | -4    | 1             | 96              |
| 1      | 20190301 | -19   | 1             | 96              |
| 1      | 20190401 | 1     | 1             | 1               |
| 1      | 20190501 | -131  | 2             | 192             |
|--------|----------|-------|---------------|-----------------|
```

The problem I'm facing is that `@Supply` and `@RecommendedQty` are referencing each other and my solution becomes too complex and hacky already as SQL Server 2008 R2 doesn't support some useful WINDOW functions

Comment: Why are you still using sql server 2008? It is no longer supported. You really need to upgrade. But I don't understand your question and I am not going to open up a spreadsheet to understand the problem.

Comment: Rows have no inherent order unless a query specifies it with `ORDER BY`.  There are many duplicate questions that show how to find the previous row *according to some order* and calculate differences, even without windowing functions.

Comment: If you do need to include data in a question, do so as tabular formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements (as you have done for some of it). As for trying to reference the previous row, this would be *far* easier if you were using a **supported** version of SQL Server; `LEAD` and `LAG` make such things trivial

Comment: There are a *lot* of questions asking about month over month or year over year calculations. The good answers typically involve using a Calendar table

Comment: I know how to get previous value, but the problem is that here is dependency between the columns I don't know how to resolve. It is best shown in Excel, I've added screenshots with the formulas. I can't upgrade SQL Server even if it is not supported :(

Comment: Replacing a link to Google with images of Google isn't what any of asked you to do.

Comment: Other questions are different because there is no circular dependency. `Supply` is using `Recommended` value from the previous period. And current `Recommended` value is using current `Supply` value.

Comment: Is your data set small enough that you could work in a temporary table with acceptable performance?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the few cases I'd recommend a cursor based solution. It doesn't scale well so if your data is large, it is a poor choice, but at least it will do what you need in a fairly understandable way

```
DECLARE @qoh INT = 95
      , @ss  INT = 58
      , @eoq INT = 96;

CREATE TABLE #data
(
     PartId INT
  ,  SalesOrderQty INT
  , SalesDate     DATE
);

INSERT INTO #data (PartId
                 , SalesOrderQty
                 , SalesDate)
VALUES (1, 75, '20190101')
     , (1, 100, '20190201')
     , (1, 115, '20190301')
     , (1, 95, '20190401')
     , (1, 132, '20190501');

;with cteOrdered as (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartID ORDER BY  SalesDate) as RowNum 
    FROM #data 
)
SELECT *, @QOH-@SS-SalesOrderQty as Supply, 1 as EOQMultiplier, @QOH as RecommendedQty
INTO #DataTemp 
FROM cteOrdered

DECLARE @PartId INT
DECLARE  @SalesOrderQty int
DECLARE  @SalesDate DATE 
DECLARE  @RowNum int
DECLARE  @Supply int
DECLARE  @EOQMultiplier int
DECLARE  @RecommendedQty int
DECLARE  @PrevRecQty int

DECLARE curMonth CURSOR FOR   
SELECT PartId , SalesOrderQty , SalesDate , RowNum , Supply , EOQMultiplier, RecommendedQty 
FROM #DataTemp
ORDER BY PartID, RowNum;

OPEN curMonth  

FETCH NEXT FROM curMonth   
INTO @PartId , @SalesOrderQty , @SalesDate , @RowNum , @Supply , @EOQMultiplier, @RecommendedQty

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    IF (@RowNum = 1) BEGIN --No prior month
        SET @Supply = @QOH - @SS - @SalesOrderQty
    END ELSE BEGIN
        SET @Supply = @PrevRecQty - @SalesOrderQty 
    END
    SET @EOQMultiplier = CEILING(ABS(@Supply*1.0/@eoq))
    if (@Supply <= 0) BEGIN
        SET @RecommendedQty = @EOQMultiplier * @eoq 
    END ELSE BEGIN 
        SET @RecommendedQty = @Supply
    END

    SET @PrevRecQty = @RecommendedQty

    UPDATE #DataTemp 
    SET Supply = @Supply, EOQMultiplier = @EOQMultiplier, RecommendedQty= @RecommendedQty
    WHERE PartId = @PartId AND RowNum = @RowNum

    FETCH NEXT FROM curMonth   
    INTO @PartId , @SalesOrderQty , @SalesDate , @RowNum , @Supply , @EOQMultiplier, @RecommendedQty
END   
CLOSE curMonth;  
DEALLOCATE curMonth; 

SELECT * FROM #DataTemp 

DROP TABLE #data 
DROP TABLE #DataTemp
```